# Python, writing to txt with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this program that asks the user to complete 10 maths questions, each time they get an answer correct, 1 point is added to their score.

```
current_class = Classes[student_class]
class_score = open(current_class, 'r+')
class_format = (name, "has a score of", Score)
class_score.write(class_format)
print(class_score.read())
```

However, when I read the .txt file it returns the error

```
TypeError: must be str, not tuple
```

I want it to print:

```
 Imran has a score of 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do,

```
class_score.write("{} has score {}".format(name, score))
```

or

```
print("{} has score {}".format(name, score), file=class_score)
```

This way you could do the following as well,

```
print(*class_format, file=class_score)
```

I would prefer the 2nd one.

Answer (score 2):

`class_format` should be:

```
class_format = "{} has a score of {}".format(name, Score)
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) (section *7.1.3.1*)

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I would be able to search  if a user (the input the same name each time the program is run) has more than 3 scores? I'm guessing I could use the any() function but I'm not too sure. I just want to make sure that the program will delete the oldest score if there is 3 scores for a user

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to build a string from the tuple.

```
class_format = (name, "has a score of", Score)
class_score.write(" ".join(class_format))
```